# How do I implement a knowledge base in a Huggingface model?

Tags: bert-language-model, transformer-model, knowledge-graph

I made a knowledge base using `COMET` on the Atomic knowledge graph, using this [tutorial](https://github.com/atcbosselut/comet-commonsense/tree/acf320a13456310bff6a29b7221a2dce552b3e2b).

I would like to include this knowledge in a regular pre-trained `BERT` model from [HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/bert-base-cased?text=Paris%20is%20the%20%5BMASK%5D%20of%20France.) to see how the model with access to this knowledge performs on a different task (sentiment analysis).

I saved the generated tuples from `COMET` in a pickle file.

Thanks!